# Why need for redirect uri when requesting OAuth access token from Google?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am trying to request an access token from Google do I can access a Google Drive account, to upload files.

I can make a an Auth request ...

```
<form method="POST" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="[YOUR SCOPE]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="[YOUR CLIENT ID]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="[YOUR RETURN URL]"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="access_type" value="offline"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Why do I need the redirect_uri if I am making an HTTP request to obtain the access token. Wouldn't the token be returned within the response body?

My app does not involve any user interaction so I am not sure why a redirect is even necessary. I don't wish to use an SDK or library, rather I would just like to use HTTP via Postman.

Answer (score 0):

> My app does not involve any user interaction

Oauth2 does require user interaction to authenticate to a users account then your going to have to request access from them.  A consent screen is displayed and the code is returned to the redirect uri

Comment: So does this mean the end user (whose account I wish to access) will have to go to a web page I to allow them to enter their username and password. Then I capture the OAuth token and use it from that point on?

Comment: yes the user will need to login and you will be able to capture a refresh token which you can use to get a new access token and use the api

Answer (score 0):

back to the basics of form submit ( without javascript), the form data will be sent to the uri you set in the `action` and the page will be redirected to what the server set it to, or page gets "reloaded" with a page that shows the response od the server.

I never tried Google OAuth2, but in general for this case, usually if your form submit is successful, it will redirect to your `redirect_uri` with the token appended on the uri as hash.

just realized u are using code grant type. so the flow is after this form submit, it will get redirected to Google IDM to authenticate and accpt consent, then redirect to `redirect_uri` with the auth code appended. then u can get the token by requesting it from the token endpoint with the code you obtained.